# What difference between build Chrome and build Server?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build Hello-World app for web. In Visual Code menu I see two variants. 
[image]

When I am tried first (Chrome) it run build process that take 1 minute. Then open Chrome and I did not seeing any result.

When I tried Server it build normal flutter app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Chrome** device will build the app and launch it in Chrome, which enables debugging (note: this work is very much in-progress and doesn't work well yet).

The **Server** device is for where Chrome cannot be launched (for example if you don't have it installed, or if the extension host is running remotely). This mode won't automatically launch a browser and might not be able to support all functionality like hot-reload-on-save or debugging.

Out of interest - how did you end up being prompted for this? I would've expected VS code to select Chrome automatically and launch with that so you don't see a confusing prompt like this unless you specifically click in the status bar to change device.